# Как найти значение которое повторяется чаще всего?

Tags: javascript

Допустим есть такой JSON:

```
[{"title":"a","cost":"56"},{"title":"b","cost":"34"},{"title":"a","cost":"233"},{"title":"c","cost":"3434"},{"title":"a","cost":"434"}]
```

Как найти title, который повторяется чаще всего ?
Вот мой вариант, но хотелось бы увидеть более правильное решение

```js
let arr = JSON.parse('[{"title":"a","cost":"56"},{"title":"b","cost":"34"},{"title":"a","cost":"233"},{"title":"c","cost":"3434"},{"title":"a","cost":"434"}]');
let names = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  names.push(arr[i].title);
}
let counts = {};
let res = 0;
names.forEach(function(x) {
  counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) + 1;
  if (counts[x] > res) {
    res += counts[x];
  }
});
let max = 0;
let maxName = '';
for (let key in counts) {
  if (max < counts[key]) {
    max = counts[key];
    maxName = key;
  }
}
console.log(maxName); // a
```

Comment: Напишите что именно Вас не устраивает в коде. Почему не хотите использовать имеющуюся реализацию.

Comment: Просто хочу узнать можно ли сделать лучше и короче тк только учусь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Нет смысла делать массив из заголовков - достаточно уже имеющегося.
2. Для словаря вместо пустого объекта лучше использовать `Object.create(null)`, чтобы не было проблем с методами в прототипе объекта. Ещё, если результат не превосходит 2<sup>31</sup>, можно использовать `~~` для приведения к инту - в большинстве случаев помогает от той же проблемы при использовании `{}` (от всего кроме `__proto__`).
3. Самых частых может быть несколько.
4. Здесь баг: `res += counts[x];` - должно быть просто `=`, а не `+=`. Хотя это значение дальше вообще почему-то не используется - непонятно, зачем тогда оно считалось.
5. `max < counts[key]` - здесь могло бы быть `counts[key] === res`, если бы в прошлом пункте было написано верно.

---

Я бы сделал так если нужен массив:

```js
var arr = JSON.parse('[{"title":"a","cost":"56"},{"title":"b","cost":"34"},{"title":"a","cost":"233"},{"title":"c","cost":"3434"},{"title":"a","cost":"434"}]');

var count = Object.create(null), max = 0, cur;

for (var x of arr) {
  if ((cur = count[x.title] = ~~count[x.title] + 1) > max) {
    max = cur;
  }
}

var res = Object.keys(count).filter(x => count[x] === max);

console.log(res);
```

и так, если нужен любой максимум:

```js
var arr = JSON.parse('[{"title":"a","cost":"56"},{"title":"b","cost":"34"},{"title":"a","cost":"233"},{"title":"c","cost":"3434"},{"title":"a","cost":"434"}]');

var count = Object.create(null), max = 0, cur, res;

for (var x of arr) {
  if ((cur = count[x.title] = ~~count[x.title] + 1) > max) {
    max = cur;
    res = x.title;
  }
}

console.log(res);
```

Comment: А можете немного объяснить что происходит в строке    `if ((cur = count[x.title] = ~~count[x.title] + 1) > max)`

Comment: @pi4yyy, `~~count[x.title]` - приводим значение `count[x.title]` к int32 (при этом undefined превратится в 0, а не в NaN, но числа больше 2**31-1 использовать нельзя), прибавляем к нему 1 и записываем в `count[x.title]` и `cur`. Затем проверяем меньше ли это значение, чем `max`.

Comment: @pi4yyy, ещё немного ответ обновил.

Answer (score 1):

данный пример имеет ряд технических недоработок, которые решаются незначительными правками:

- ©Самых частых может быть несколько
- вызов `obj.increment('increment')` `obj.increment('max')` `obj.increment('min')` всё поломает

спасибо @Qwertiy за замечание

предлагаю его рассматривать в ракурсе стилистического оформления (повторяемый код должен быть в функции)

```js
void function () {
 let obj = {
  increment(_key) {
   if (!this[_key]) this[_key] = 0
   this[_key]++
  },
  get min() { return; },
  get max() {
   let key = null
   let count = 0
   Object.keys(this).forEach(_key => {
    if (count < this[_key]) {
     count = this[_key]
     key = _key
    }
   })
   return { key, count };
  },
 }
 Object.keys(obj).forEach(_key => {
  Object.defineProperty(obj, _key, {
   enumerable: false
  })
 })
 obj.increment('a')
 obj.increment('a')
 obj.increment('c')
 obj.increment('c')
 obj.increment('c')
 obj.increment('b')
 let { key, count } = obj.max
 var co = co || document.getElementById('co')
 console.log(`ключ:"${key}" количество повторений:"${count}"`)
 co.innerHTML = `ключ:"${key}" количество повторений:"${count}"`
}()
```

```html
<div id="co"></div>
```

Comment: 1. Зачем `defineProperty`? 2. Что будет, когда придёт ключ `increment`? 3. А если `__proto__`?

Comment: @Qwertiy 1. enumerable = перечислимый = false 2. поэтому он больше не придёт 3. `__proto__` и `prototype` enumerable = false  https://learn.javascript.ru/descriptors-getters-setters

Comment: И что что false? `if (!this[_key]) this[_key] = 0` - тут не проверяется перечислимость. `this[_key]++` - и тут - тоже.

Comment: @Qwertiy, но работает же :). тут [descriptor](https://learn.javascript.ru/descriptors-getters-setters#%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85) всё написано, и про `enumerable` - тоже

Comment: @Qwertiy, :) как думаете, почету использован `void` а не скобочки или `+` ...

Comment: Что работает, если нет? https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmBgb.png

Comment: @Qwertiy, благодарю за важное замечание. так как на счёт void?)

Comment: `void` - чтобы сделать function expression. Не `+` - чтобы при вставке после других скриптов не создало нежелательное выражение вместе с ними. С тем же успехом можно было поставить `!` или `~`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, совершенно верно) но читается же лучше. как и разнесение по функциям. три вложенных тернарных оператора круто до тех пор, пока через месяц не пришлось лезть в СВОЙжеж ктож его знал раньше что всё забудется (утрирую)  код. ещё раз спасибо за замечание, спать пойду, пожалуй я.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, но ваша реализация читается лучше ...

```js
const json = JSON.parse('[{"title":"a","cost":"56"},{"title":"b","cost":"34"},{"title":"a","cost":"233"},{"title":"c","cost":"3434"},{"title":"a","cost":"434"}]');

const titleCounts = json.reduce(( memo, item ) => ({ ...memo, [item.title]: ( memo[item.title] || 0 ) + 1 }), {}); // Считаем сколько раз каждый из `title` встречается
const mostFrequent = Object.keys(titleCounts).reduce(( prev, cur ) => titleCounts[prev] > titleCounts[cur] ? prev : cur); // Ищем ключ с наибольшим значением

console.log(titleCounts);
console.log(mostFrequent);
```